# if Vlookup is the same, then add

Tags: vba, excel

I have this, and I want that if there are 2 same A code from worksheet 1, add the B value column in column E in worksheet 2. Can you help me for that?

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you need ? You have done everything you are asking in your example

Comment: For exemple, if in worksheet 1 colomn A I add "text text (2012-R-0001)" with 10-200 in column B.
I want taht in worksheet 2, it add the 2 same value like 2012-R-0001 in A and 50-809 (40-609+10-200) in E. (dont worry about the SUM, there are actually numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below UDF function. This can be directly apply to any cell. Please see the screenshot.

```
Public Function udfvlookup(a As Range, b As Range) As String
    Dim findtext As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim out As Double
    findtext = a.Value
    For Each cell In b
        If cell Like "*" & findtext & "*" Then
            out = out + cell.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    Next
    udfvlookup = out
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I tested your solution but it seems to doesnt work :

[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKLGA.png

Comment: It seems to work, but it should show "5,25" (1+4.25) but it shows "5", I think there is a problem with number with coma. can you solve it please ?

Comment: change the declaration for out as Double instead of Long. It will work

Comment: Welcome always @babou

Comment: little tip : If i offset sheet1.column B to sheet1.column P it doesnt work anymore, do you know why ? :P

Comment: Try out = out + cell.Offset(0,15) for column P

Comment: if your data is in column P then the offset value should be 15 starting from A.